# SQL Server 2012: ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN MyColumn1 fails because one or more objects access this column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains `MyColumn1` with user defined datatype of `CustomDatatype INT NOT NULL`. I need to change this column to a `VARCHAR(5)`, but I am getting the following errors:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The object 'CustomDatatype' is dependent on column 'MyColumn1'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 12
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN MyColumn1 failed because one or more objects access this column.

This does not seem to be related to an index or foreign key reference which I would omit to drop before altering the column datatype, this seems to be directly related to the originally used custom defined datatype `CustomDatatype` on this column.

How can I change `MyColumn1`'s datatype without dropping the `CustomDatatype` because that could create apocalyptic scenario in my system or dropping the table?

Thanks

**Update (2018-07-31):  I found a response to the same question in different forum where it states:** "...This is the problem with UDT columns. You will need to drop all the columns of this type first in all tables (and may be in functions / SPs, views), then delete the type and create correct type, then re-create all the columns..." (Naomi 2011) *from Microsoft (August 2, 2011) web: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b7bf0f04-dee8-4751-803b-4c3e1f7f7c70/how-to-change-column-nametype-of-user-defined-table-type?forum=transactsql*

**So far the only viable solutions I came up with are to:**

1. Create a copy of the table (script it out with all
   dependencies i.e.: triggers, indexes, keys, etc.) Drop the original
   table (which is ok to do even though custom datatypes are specified) and then recreate the table again with the new datatype column.
2. If the table cannot be dropped (for some reason) rename the old
   datatype column, create a new column with the original column name
   with the right datatype. Move the data from the old (renamed) column
   into the new one (make sure to mind the triggers,etc.). Then force
   to recompile all the Sprocs and refresh all the views which are
   dependent.

Comment: Can you script out the type and the table to create a short, self-contained repro?

Comment: ..so far I came up with a possible workaround with renaming the original column and creating a new one with the desired datatype (I will probably have to refresh all the views, SPs, etc.). Could you pls. expand on what you are suggesting? The original (before the change) datatype has been defined as CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CustomDatatype] FROM [int];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So far the only viable solutions I came up with are to:**

1) Create a copy of the table (script it out with all dependencies i.e.: triggers, indexes, keys, etc.) Drop the original table (which is ok to do even though custom datatypes are specified) and then recreate the table again with the new datatype column.

2) If the table cannot be dropped (for some reason) rename the old datatype column, create a new column with the original column name with the right datatype. Move the data from the old (renamed) column into the new one (make sure to mind the triggers,etc.). Then force to recompile all the Sprocs and refresh all the views which are dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if there is any Index added for those column?

If yes,

> you will need to **drop and recreate the index**.

once you drop the constraints and index , you can alter the column.

```
alter table Table1 
alter column MyColumn1 varchar(5);
```

Then **re-create constraints and index.**

Comment: ...no index as explained above in my question.